# XNA Silverlight 5 3D Model Position

Tags: xna, collision-detection, silverlight

I am use to XNA and starting to learn XNA for Silverlight 5. My Question is that in XNA when you create a Model and load it using content.load you are able to access the models Position, scale etc.. In Silverlight XNA these options are not available. It would be possible  to change the Models position using World Translate, but I need the models position for collision detectection using boundingSphere Any Advice??

Answer (score 1):

XNA should allow you to do something like this to create your `BoundingSphere`, so long as you get grab the vertex buffer for your model.

```
List<Vector3> vertices = GetModelVertices(scale);    
BoundingSphere sphere = BoundingSphere.CreateFromPoints(vertices);

// Gets the vertices that make up a model
public List<Vector3> GetModelVertices(float Scale)
{
    List<Vector3> verts = new List<Vector3>();

    VertexPositionNormalTexture[] vertices = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[numVertices];
    vertexBuffer.GetData(vertices);
    foreach (VertexPositionNormalTexture vertex in vertices)
    {
        verts.Add(vertex.Position * Scale);
    }

    return verts;
}
```

Alternatively, you should be able to iterate through each `ModelMesh` part in your model, and each of those have a `BoundingSphere` that you can query. From that you can call `BoundingSphere.CreateMerged(BoundingSphere, BoundingSphere)`, for each of the bounding spheres on the `ModelMesh` objects, and combine them to get your final bounding sphere.